# constructor for ThreadPoolExecutor subclass

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

If i extend ThreadPoolExecutor, is there any way to reuse the factory methods such as:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

Or do i have to call the constructor of my ThreadPoolExecutor subclass and input all the parameters:

```
class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  ...
  public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can't extend static methods.  You could make your own static method that returns the type of Executor you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no possible way to do the first one. I would recommend doing the other way:

```
class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  ...
  public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
  };
  ...
}
```

Because it is the only way to do it.